# How can I use "group_by" and "mutate" in R without creating a long list of attributes?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am relatively new to R so I apologize if I am not using the correct terminology to describe my issue.

I often use "group_by" and "mutate" together (from the dplyr package) in order to add new variables to my dataframe. For example, I use the code below to calculate county population sums grouped by state ("fips") and year ("year").

```
 county <- county %>% group_by(fips, year) %>% mutate(pop.sum = sum(pop, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Whenever I do this, however, it creates what I believe is an attribute called "groups":

[image]

I am not sure what this is, or why it has such a long list of rows. I have been able to "remove" this attribute by running:

```
 attr(county, "groups") <- NULL
```

But this ends up causing other problems down the line. For instance, if I try to merge this dataframe after removing the "groups" attribute, I will get the following error:

```
Error: `.data` is a corrupt grouped_df, the `"groups"` attribute must be a data frame
```

Can anyone explain what this "groups" attribute is? Also, am I doing something wrong when I use 'group_by' and 'mutate' that is creating this attribute?

Thanks!

Comment: did you try add `ungroup`?

Comment: When you use `group_by`, you'll get a group attribute. That's just how `dplyr` stores that information. To safely remove it, pipe your data to `ungroup()`. Randomly getting attributes to NULL is a dangerous idea in general. I'm curious why you are trying so hard to remove it.

Comment: I did not know about the ungroup command - thank you!